# Can such a point exist?

Tags: general-topology

I applied the Baire category theorem and I arrived at a problem that can be formulated as follows. Suppose $(F_{n})$ is an increasing sequence of closed sets in  $\mathbb{R}^{d}$, and set 
$$F:=\bigcup_{k\geq1}\bigcap_{n\geq k}\partial F_n .$$ Suppose $F$ is a closed set (we know it) and has  no isolated points. My question is: can there be a point $x_{0}\in F$ such that every open neighborhood $V$ of 
$x_{0}$ contains the closure of an open set $\omega$ such that $\omega$ contains $x_{0}$ and  the boundary of $\omega$ is in $F$?

Comment: No, F can be empty.  By boundary of omega is in  F, do you actually mean is a subset of F?

Comment: Yes: $\partial\omega\subset F$.

Comment: But why no? Do you have a proof?

Comment: For all n in N, let F_n = [-n,n];  bd F_n = {-n,n}.   Thus the boundaries are pairwise disjoint and F empty.

Comment: Sorry! You example does not prove anything...

Comment: There may no such $x_0$  even when $ F\ne \phi.$ But it seems you are asking whether  such an $x_0 $ could exist for some family $(F_n)_n.$ Could you clarify this?

Comment: I am asking : either prove that such an $x_{0}$ does not exist under the given conditions, or give a counter example showing that such an $x_{0}$ can very well exit.

Comment: Yes. Suppose that $F$ is not empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want an example of a sequence where such $x_0$ exists, take $F_i=F$ to be the constant sequence of Cantor sets in ${\mathbb R}$ ($d=1$) and let $x_0$ be a point of $F$ which does not belong to the closure of any complementary interval of $F$ in ${\mathbb R}$. Similarly, taking each $F_i=F$ to be the unit circle in ${\mathbb R^2}$ gives you an example of a sequence where $x_0$ does not exist. If you insist on strictly increasing sequences of subsets, my examples can be easily modified to satisfy this property as well.

Comment: Could you please explain why every neighborhood $V$ of $x_{0}$ contains another neighborhood $\omega$ of $x_{0}$ such that the boundary of $\omega$ is in $F$? I didn't get this point very well.

Comment: @M.Rahmat: By the definition, $x_0$ is the limit of two sequences $y_n, z_n\in F$, converging to $x_0$ from the left and from the right respectively. This gives you a sequences of intervals $\omega_n=(y_n,z_n)$ forming a basis of topology at $x_0$ such that $\partial \omega_n\subset F$.